# Showing linear independence without Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

So if $(I,x_1)$ and $(I,x_2)$ with $$x_2(t)=x_1(t)\int_{t_0}^t\frac{1}{x_1(s)^2}e^{-\int_{t_0}^sp(r)dr}ds,\quad (t_0,t\in I)$$are solutions to$$x''+p(t)x'+q(t)x=0$$where $p,q$ are continuous and we want to show that $(I,x_1)$ and $(I,x_2)$ are linearly independent we usually find the determine of the Wronskian matrix and show that is not equal to $0$.

However if one wants to show this (in this setup) without Wronskian how would you approach it? Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 2):

Two nonzero functions are linearly independent if and only if their ratio is non-constant.
In particular, if $x_1(t)$ is not identically $0$, and $x_2(t) = x_1(t) \int_{t_0}^t g(s)\; ds$ where $g(s)$ is continuous and not identically $0$ on an interval where $x_1(t)$ is nonzero, then $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are  linearly independent.